# Can´t Run or Export Android Application after incorporting Facebook sdk to my project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I don´t know what I did...  Everything was working well, had to battle a while to get facebook login working, and doing what I wanted to do...  Finally it was ready, so I proceeded to Export Android Application... First error had to do with Dalvik code error 1 something... So I look for duplicates .jars in my folder, erased libraries in java build path, cleaned the project, etc, as proposed in some stackoverflow answers...

Stopped getting that kind of error but now I can´t even Run the application, now I get some errors like: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded, or:  Unable to execute dex: Java Heap Space.

In my windows machine it gets stuck until some memory related error is displayed...  in my Mac the Eclipse is forceclosed in most occasions ...  I tried to roll back and took off the facebook sdk part, but nothing, now I can´t run/export my app even as it was before...  I guess I did something wrong in the cleaning or something in the Eclipse parameters..

Please help, I´m dying here..  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself to help others:

1.Check there´s no duplicate .jar anywhere in your project.
2.Go to eclipse.ini in your Eclipse folder, and modify to this, or greater: 
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
3.Save and restart Eclipse
4.Go to Project -> uncheck Build Automatically
5.Go to Project -> Clean... , clean both the library project and your app project
6.Export your app as a signed APK while Build Automatically is still disabled
7.Re-enable Build Automatically and everything should be back to normal as before